# WPF Left click and drag

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been trying to work with the mouse event handlers.  Using MouseDown only seems to work with the right mouse button.  And PreviewMouseLeftButton doesn't activate the MouseMove event until I release the left button.

So this code:

```
    private void NewButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var test = e.LeftButton;
        var test2 = e.RightButton;
        if (!bButtonIsDown)
        {
            bButtonIsDown = true;
            Button mover = (Button)sender;
            pntEnterPoint = e.GetPosition(this.cnvsLinkScreen);

            cnvsLinkScreen.MouseMove += CnvsLinkScreen_MouseMove;
            cnvsLinkScreen.MouseUp += CnvsLinkScreen_MouseUp;
            
            spMover = (StackPanel)((Button)sender).Parent;
            pntPreviousPoint.X = Canvas.GetLeft(spMover);
            pntPreviousPoint.Y = Canvas.GetTop(spMover);

        }
    }

    private void NewButton_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Button mover = (Button)sender;
        StackPanel spMover = (StackPanel)((Button)sender).Parent; 
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {

            // Inititate the drag-and-drop operation.
            FindChild<StackPanel>(cnvsLinkScreen, "CSVImport");
            pntEnterPoint = e.GetPosition(this.cnvsLinkScreen);
            Canvas.SetLeft(spMover, pntEnterPoint.X + 1);
            Canvas.SetTop(spMover, pntEnterPoint.Y + 1);
        }
    }
```

Works but with right button only.  When enabling the event handler with:

```
newButton.MouseDown += NewButton_MouseDown;
```

That event handler will not get touched with the left mouse button, which I think is odd.

I've done a good amount of reading out there and people refer to thePreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event handler but when I use that in place (same code) the cnvsLinkScreen.MouseMove += CnvsLinkScreen_MouseMove doesn't fire until I let go of the left mouse button (button up) then the StackPanel drags until I click and drop it.

I set breakpoints and see that the event handler is getting set, but it's just not working until after the left button is released.  Clearly I'm missing something with the event handlers on this.

Why isn't the MouseDown event handler not even firing with a left mouse button down; only a right mouse button down?

Comment: Note that WPF has built-in support for drag and drop: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/drag-and-drop-overview

Comment: Yes, I am doing this to get the objects in the canvas, but when I try to do this to move them, the objects don't slide on the canvas but instead the mouse icon changes and the object stays in place until I let go of the mouse.  I want the animation of the object moving when dragging it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with [Routed Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview). Unlike with normal events, a routed event can be [marked as handled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/marking-routed-events-as-handled-and-class-handling), after which no further handlers for that event will be called.

`MouseDown` and `MouseMove` are [bubbling routed events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/marking-routed-events-as-handled-and-class-handling#preview-tunneling-events-vs-bubbling-events-and-event-handling), meaning they start at the deepest elements (the ones inside the button) and then "bubble" their way up, through their parents, toward the `Window`. Any parent can register a handler for these events and it will be called when the event reaches that parent's level. However if any child marks the event as handled, the event will never reach the parent and the parent's handler will never be called.

This is what's happening here. `Button` has a handler for `MouseDown` *internally*. When `Button` decides it has been clicked, it raises its own `Click` event and *marks `MouseDown` as handled*. `Button` also seems to handle `MouseMove`, but only while a click is in progress. This is why your event handlers don't get called during a left-click, because left-click triggers a "click" which ends up handling those events before they make it out of the `Button`.

`PreviewMouseDown` and `PreviewMouseMove`, on the other hand, are both [tunneling routed events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/marking-routed-events-as-handled-and-class-handling#preview-tunneling-events-vs-bubbling-events-and-event-handling), meaning they start from the broadest parent (the `Window`) and work their way inwards toward the exact point of the cursor. Tunneling events happen *before* bubbling events; the mouse input first tunnels in toward the cursor, then bubbles back up.

**If you attach event handlers to `PreviewMouseDown` and `PreviewMouseMove` instead of `MouseDown` and `MouseMove`, you will see all the mouse input you expect.**

Funny side note: you can actually play the same trick on `Button` that `Button` is playing on you. If you mark `PreviewMouseDown` as handled before it gets inside the `Button`, then it will never raise its `Click` event.

Comment: I'm having the same effect with the PreviewMouseDown event where I click on the image(stackpanel) and try to drag it and it doesn't go anywhere.  But when I release the button it moves the image around until I click to release it again.  Just to make sure it wasn't in my code, I took out the !ButtonDown. It doesn't seem the MouseMove event takes affect until after I release the left button...

Comment: Actually, I took off the check for which mouse button is being hit and the right button still works.  But the left does not.  So I commented out the line: if (!bButtonIsDown ) so both mouse buttons will trigger the action.  But again, the right button works as expected, the left doesn't until I release the button.

Comment: Ah, got it! I had to set e.handled = true and now it works as expected! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank god, you exist. I wanted to end myself, but now I understand how this works